# How to mock dependency of dependency with Vitest

Tags: mocking, dependencies, vite, vitest

I have a test setup with vite and have a dependency of a dependency that needs some mocked options in order to run properly, I currently have it in a `__mocks__/nestedDependency.js` file.
Also in my `test/setup.ts` file I have a `vi.mock('nestedDependency')`, however it does not seem to catch it in any way

I previously had the setup with `jest` and this exact setup worked. Only thing I have migrated from that setup is instead of using `jest.requireActual('nestedDependency')` I am now using `vi.importActual('nestedDependency')` for my mocking purposes.

Comment: I am running into the same issue. I realize that my nested dependency is bundled to use `require` and `vitest` won't mock a `require` call. Trying to sort it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue and my solution **might** help you out. I am in a monorepo. The top level package is `panel` which requires `state` and `common`. `state` also requires `common`. I need `common` mocked to be the same even though it's nested through `state`.

I realized that when I ran the tests for `panel`, that `state` would be accessed via it's bundle, which was using `require` calls, which `vitest` will not mock.

I updated my test config to use `alias`

```js
// the source code only uses import
const unbundledState = resolve(__dirname, '../state/src/index');

export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    environment: 'jsdom',
    setupFiles: ['./tests/test.setup'],
    globalSetup: ['./tests/test.global'],
    alias: {
      '@cai/state': unbundledState,
    },
  },
});
```

This made `vitest` run through `import` statements instead of `require` statements and thus things were mocked. So my solution works if the nested dependency happens to use `import` before being bundled.

This makes me think if it weren't, something like [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire) could work for you.

Answer (score -2):

Double-check that you've got all your devDependencies in order. Peek at your `package.json` to make sure you've got the likes of `@vitejs/plugin-vue` and any other testing-related pals installed and chillin'.

Next, give your project structure a once-over:

- Ensure your `__mocks__` directory is sitting pretty at the top-level of your project.
- Make sure the `nestedDependency.js` file lives snugly inside that `__mocks__` folder.

Now, for the mocking magic in your `test/setup.ts` file:

- You mentioned `vi.mock('nestedDependency')`, but that's not quite right. Instead, you usually want to do something like this:

  ```
  import { mock } from 'jest';
  mock('nestedDependency');
  ```

And let's not forget your import statements. If you're using `vi.importActual('nestedDependency')`, make sure you're pulling in the actual module properly in your test files:

```
 `import { nestedDependency } from 'nestedDependency';`
```

Now, the Vite configuration itself might need a little nudge:

- Make sure your `vite.config.js` is set up correctly to deal with modules and mocks. You might need to clue Vite in on handling mocks by adding something like this:

  ```
  export default {
    ...,
    optimizeDeps: {
      include: ['nestedDependency'], // Add your dependency here
    },
  };
  ```

And if you're still scratching your head after all this, don't forget to clear out the Vite cache and rebuild your project:

```
  vite build --clearCache
```

If you're still banging your head against the wall, toss me some more details about your project structure, what exactly you're trying to do, and any error messages that are giving you grief.

Comment: `--clearCache` doesn't exist. Your instructions also use jest mocking, not vitest. Also useless phrases like "pals chillin'", "sitting pretty", "lives snuggly" are totally unappreciated in a technical discussion.